# What emblems can you earn in ranked League games?

Tags: league-of-legends

The new ranked system in League involves, among other things, emblems that can be earned. The only two I've seen thus far are for winning 3 games in a row, and playing more than 100 games. What other emblems can be earned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's also one called "Recruit", for when you first join a certain league:

[image: recruit badge]

I'm not aware of any others.

Also, since there appears to be some confusion, the Veteran emblem is awarded when you have played 100 or more games in the same league.  Moving up and down divisions (i.e. from Silver IV to Silver III) doesn't change what league you are in, so this emblem is effectively for playing 100 games in the same rating tier (Silver, Gold, etc.).

Comment: Im fairly certain these are the only ones currently. I always feel bad for that person with the veteran emblem XD

Comment: There isn't even one for 10 win hotstreak, which is dumb, because I actually achieved it in silver and wanted a different emblem :P

Comment: @Ravekner I have the veteran emblem!  It's taken me over 100 games to get from Silver IV to Silver I, I'm not too ashamed of that.

Comment: Ah. That makes a little more sense I suppose. I had always assumed it was people that had been stuck in the same tier like silver IV with a veteran emblem. But if you can get it for being in all of silver for over 100 games its not so bad.

Comment: Wait, isn't the Veteran emblem only ment for a division? Doesn't the emblem get removed when you go from Silver IV to Silver III?

Comment: @Joetjah No, it's for a tier.  FYI: you can give him the bounty, there's only 3 emblems.